# SSAS Named query can't be added asa dimension

Tags: ssas, olap-cube, dimension, named-query

I have a SSAS cube. My warehouse is correctly configured with foreign keys etc and my normal dimensions all work.  I have now made a named query that is intended to be used as a hierarchy, combining 3 of these dimensions into one.  I have made the named query and created the relationships and shown the table in the cube but I can't add it as a dimension for some reason.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you got an error or just option is not available?

Comment: I don't get an error. In the cube view the bar at the top entity definition is gray and not blue like the other dimensions or yellow like the fact tables.  When I try and add dimensions to the cube it in not available as an option

Comment: Did you create a dimension object from your named query?

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly?  In the dimensions section of the cube I tried to add it as a dimension, but I don't know if that is what you mean or if there is a way to define it as a dimension so that I can then add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you're looking at it in the Data Source View and not in the Cube Design window? You need to add the table to the Cube Design so you can see make it a dimension/measure

Comment: I am definitely in the cube designer and have "shown" the table in the data source view under cube structure.  I have tried to use the dimensions section to add it but it does not appear in the list

Comment: On the left side of the Solution Explorer, go to "Dimensions", right click and choose "add dimension". Can you add this named query as a dimension?

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew it was something simple I was missing.